# MVC infrastructure

Tags: python, model-view-controller

```
import random

class Spinner(object):

@staticmethod
def getSpin():
    newSpin = random.randint(1,6)
    return newSpin

class Player(object):

def __init__(self,name):
    self.position = 1
    self.name = name

def setName(self,name):
    self.name = name

def changePosition(self,number):
    self.position = self.position + number

def setPosition(self,pos):
    self.position = pos
    return self.position

def getPosition(self):
    return self.position

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def spin(self):
    newSpin = Spinner.getSpin()
    self.position = self.position + newSpin
    print(str(self.name) + "'s spin was: " + str(newSpin))

class Display():
def buildLadders():
    ladders = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
    ladders[0][0] = 2
    ladders[0][1] = 7
    ladders[1][0] = 4
    ladders[1][1] = 5
    return ladders

def buildChutes():
    chutes = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
    chutes[0][0] = 9
    chutes[0][1] = 2
    chutes[1][0] = 6
    chutes[1][1] = 3
    return chutes

 class Check(Player):
def checkLadders(self):
    ladders = Display.buildLadders()
    for i in range(0,len(ladders),1):
        if self.getPosition() == ladders[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(ladders[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Ladder! from " + \
                  str(ladders[i][0]) +" to " + str(ladders[i][1]))

def checkChutes(self):
    chutes = Display.buildChutes()
    for i in range(0,len(chutes),1):
        if self.getPosition() == chutes[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(chutes[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Chutes! from " + \
                  str(chutes[i][0]) + " to " + str(chutes[i][1]))

def checkQuestions(num):
    one = random.randint(num,num*10)
    two = random.randint(num,num*10)
    listqq = [one,two]
    return listqq

class Controller(object):
def __init__(self,names):
    self.winner = ''
    self.players = []
    for n in names:
        p = Player(n)
        self.players.append(p)

def move(self):
    players = self.players
    winner = self.winner
    click = ''
    count = 1
    while True:
        for i in range(0,len(players)):
            if winner == '' and click != 'e':
                print("----" + str(players[i].getName()) + "'s TURN----")
                click = input("Press r to roll or e to exit: ")
                while click != 'r' and click != 'e':
                    click = input("Press r to roll or e to exit: ")
                if click == 'r' and click != 'e':
                    count = count + 1
                    listqq = Check.checkQuestions(count)
                    answer = input(str(listqq[0]) + ' + ' + str(listqq[1]) +' is:')
                    if answer == str(listqq[0]+listqq[1]):
                        print(str(players[i].getName()) + "'s initial position is " \
                                + str(players[i].getPosition()))
                        View(players).display()
                        players[i].spin()
                        Check.checkLadders(players[i])
                        Check.checkChutes(players[i])
                    else:
                        pass
                    if players[i].getPosition() >= 12:
                        players[i].position = players[i].setPosition(12 - (players[i].getPosition() - 12))
                    print(str(players[i].getName()) + "'s new position is " \
                            + str(players[i].getPosition()))
                    View(players).display()
            if players[i].getPosition() == 12:
                winner = players[i].getName()
        if click == 'e' and click != 'r':
            print('Bye')
            break
        if winner != '':
            print(str(winner) + " is the winner!!!")
            break

class View(Player):
def __init__(self,player):
    self.players = player

def display(self):
    players = self.players
    listof = [9,10,11,12,8,7,6,5,1,2,3,4]
    ladders = Display.buildLadders()
    chutes = Display.buildChutes()
    board = [[]] * 3
    for i in range(len(players)):
        for j in range(len(listof)):
            if self.players[i].position == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'X'
    for j in range(len(listof)):
        for i in range(len(ladders)):
            if ladders[i][0] == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'L'
    for j in range(len(listof)):
        for i in range(len(chutes)):
            if chutes[i][0] == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'C'
    for i in range(0,4):
        board[0] = board[0] + [listof[i]]
    for i in range(4,8):
        board[1] = board[1] + [listof[i]]
    for i in range(8,12):
        board[2] = board[2] + [listof[i]]
    for row in board:
        for num in row:
            if num == 'X':
                print(" X", end=" ")
            if num == 'L':
                print(" L", end= " ")
            if num == 'C':
                print(" C", end= " ")
            if num != 'X' and num != 'L' and num != 'C':
                if 10 <= num <= 20:
                    print(num,end=" ")
            if num != 'X' and num != 'L' and num!= 'C':
                if 1 <= num <= 9:
                    print(str(num).rjust(2), end= " ")
        print()


def main():
n = input("Please enter number of players: ")
names  = []
for i in range (0,int(n)):
    name = input("Please input your name: ")
    names.append(name)
game = Controller(names)
game.move()
while True:
    ask = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)")
    if ask == 'y':
        game = Controller(names)
        game.move()
    if ask == 'n':
        print("Bye, see you again!")
        break
 main()
```

fixed version:

```
import random

 class Player(object):

def __init__(self,name):
    self.position = 1
    self.name = name

def setName(self,name):
    self.name = name

def changePosition(self,number):
    self.position = self.position + number

def setPosition(self,pos):
    self.position = pos
    return self.position

def spin(self):
    newSpin = self.getSpin()
    self.position = self.position + newSpin
    print(str(self.name) + "'s spin was: " + str(newSpin))

def checkLadders(self):
    ladders = self.buildLadders()
    for i in range(0,len(ladders),1):
        if self.position == ladders[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(ladders[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Ladder! from " + \
                  str(ladders[i][0]) +" to " + str(ladders[i][1]))

def checkChutes(self):
    chutes = self.buildChutes()
    for i in range(0,len(chutes),1):
        if self.position == chutes[i][0]:
            self.position = self.setPosition(chutes[i][1])
            print(str(self.name) + " Landed on a Chutes! from " + \
                  str(chutes[i][0]) + " to " + str(chutes[i][1]))
@staticmethod
def checkQuestions(num):
    one = random.randint(num,num*10)
    two = random.randint(num,num*10)
    listqq = [one,two]
    return listqq

@staticmethod
def getSpin():
    newSpin = random.randint(1,6)
    return newSpin

@staticmethod
def buildLadders():
    ladders = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
    ladders[0][0] = 2
    ladders[0][1] = 7
    ladders[1][0] = 4
    ladders[1][1] = 5
    return ladders

@staticmethod
def buildChutes():
    chutes = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
    chutes[0][0] = 9
    chutes[0][1] = 2
    chutes[1][0] = 6
    chutes[1][1] = 3
    return chutes


class Controller(object):
def __init__(self,names):
    self.winner = ''
    self.players = []
    for n in names:
        p = Player(n)
        self.players.append(p)

def move(self):
    players = self.players
    winner = self.winner
    click = ''
    count = 1
    while True:
        for i in range(0,len(players)):
            if winner == '' and click != 'e':
                print("----" + str(players[i].name) + "'s TURN----")
                click = input("Press r to roll or e to exit: ")
                while click != 'r' and click != 'e':
                    click = input("Press r to roll or e to exit: ")
                if click == 'r' and click != 'e':
                    count = count + 1
                    listqq = Player.checkQuestions(count)
                    answer = input(str(listqq[0]) + ' + ' + str(listqq[1]) +' is:')
                    if answer == str(listqq[0]+listqq[1]):
                        print(str(players[i].name) + "'s initial position is " \
                                + str(players[i].position))
                        View(players).display()
                        players[i].spin()
                        Player.checkLadders(players[i])
                        Player.checkChutes(players[i])
                    else:
                        pass
                    if players[i].position >= 12:
                        players[i].position = players[i].setPosition(12 - (players[i].getPosition() - 12))
                    print(str(players[i].name) + "'s new position is " \
                            + str(players[i].position))
                    View(players).display()
            if players[i].position == 12:
                winner = players[i].name
        if click == 'e' and click != 'r':
            print('Bye')
            break
        if winner != '':
            print(str(winner) + " is the winner!!!")
            break

class View():
def __init__(self,player):
    self.players = player

def display(self):
    players = self.players
    listof = [9,10,11,12,8,7,6,5,1,2,3,4]
    ladders = Player.buildLadders()
    chutes = Player.buildChutes()
    board = [[]] * 3
    for i in range(len(players)):
        for j in range(len(listof)):
            if self.players[i].position == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'X'
    for j in range(len(listof)):
        for i in range(len(ladders)):
            if ladders[i][0] == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'L'
    for j in range(len(listof)):
        for i in range(len(chutes)):
            if chutes[i][0] == listof[j]:
                listof[j] = 'C'
    for i in range(0,4):
        board[0] = board[0] + [listof[i]]
    for i in range(4,8):
        board[1] = board[1] + [listof[i]]
    for i in range(8,12):
        board[2] = board[2] + [listof[i]]
    for row in board:
        for num in row:
            if num == 'X':
                print(" X", end=" ")
            if num == 'L':
                print(" L", end= " ")
            if num == 'C':
                print(" C", end= " ")
            if num != 'X' and num != 'L' and num != 'C':
                if 10 <= num <= 20:
                    print(num,end=" ")
            if num != 'X' and num != 'L' and num!= 'C':
                if 1 <= num <= 9:
                    print(str(num).rjust(2), end= " ")
        print()


def main():
n = input("Please enter number of players: ")
names  = []
for i in range (0,int(n)):
    name = input("Please input your name: ")
    names.append(name)
game = Controller(names)
game.move()
while True:
    ask = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n)")
    if ask == 'y':
        game = Controller(names)
        game.move()
    if ask == 'n':
        print("Bye, see you again!")
        break
```

main()

Is this following the MVC infrastructure? How to know if it fits the MVC structure or not? Thanks. Does we have to put each model,view,and controller in different module for it to be described as following the MVC structure?

Comment: Before asking if this is MVC there are some other strange things to fix (besides the indentation). Classes with just static methods are semantically no classes but just functions crammed into a class definition. Trivial getters and setters are ”unpythonic” — just access the attribute. `Check` and `View` should not inherit from `Player`. Inheritance is a *is a* relatationship and neither `Check` nor `View` *is* a `Player`. How classes are distributed over several modules or not does not affect the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First off the program is not really object oriented. `View` is instanciated every time when the game state has to be displayed just to call the one and only method.  Classes with just the `__init__()` and one other method are a code smell because, like in this case, it's just a function crammed into a class for no good reason.  The same can be said about `Control` — also just the `__init__()` and one additional method that get's called exactly once right after instanciating the object and directly after the call the object isn't used anymore.

Taking those ”fake” classes and considering the amount of static methods it seems you are under the impression classes automatically lead to object oriented programs — they don't.  And there is nothing wrong with using functions instead of artificially introducing unnecessary complexity with classes that are just syntactically classes.  Functions are objects too in Python, so when you have a display *function* it's okay to pass that around as „view” part of an MVC pattern.  It's a callable object.

Which brings us to the MVC question: Supposing `Player` is the model then it should not interact with the user by printing stuff.  Display and input is for the view to handle.  So `Control` isn't a controller because the function in disguise also heavily interacts with the user via `print()` and `input()`.